# Jolt transform: extract nested array from an object

Tags: java, json, transform, jolt

I have JSON Input as below

```json
{
  "data": [
    {
      "items": [
        {
          "item": "R11",
          "code": "8611A"
        },
        {
          "item": "R2",
          "code": "8611B"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to extract items array as below

```json
[
  {
    "item": "R11",
    "code": "8611A"
  },
  {
    "item": "R2",
    "code": "8611B"
  }
]
```

Please copy and paste the above INPUT and OUTPUT https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/#inception
I have tested  `[{"operation":"shift","spec":{"data":{"*":""}}}]`
But it returns `{"items" : [ {...}, {...} ] }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a **shift** transformation as below

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": { //might be replaced with "data"
        "*": {
          "*": //might be replaced with "items"
          { 
            "@": "" 
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

where the asterisks wildcards represent the array **data**, its indexes, and the array **items** respectively. The **"@":""** represents the **items** as array of objects with no key.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Barbaros , It worked.
After many trails , I got one more alternative ```[{"operation":"shift","spec":{"data":{"*":{"items":""}}}}] ```

Comment: you're welcome @SR , yes that might also be used as an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative Spec:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "data": {
        "*": {
          "items": ""
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer

```
[{
  "operation": "shift",
  "spec": {
    "data": {
      "0": {
        "*": ""
      }
    }
  }
}]
```